# Problem with Migrating Rspec Controller Tests from Rails 4.2.10 to Rails 5.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

Old Rails 4.2.10 line:

```
post :show, "Some XML as String"
```

to Rails 5.1.4

```
post :show, params: { ??? }
```

So what is the key value pair I add here?

Edit:
So currently in the tests its written like this:

```
let(:logout_request_xml) { "<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap-env:Body>...more stuff...</soap-env:Body></soap-env:Envelope>" }
...
post :show, logout_request_xml
```

Comment: Have you tried `post :show, params: "Some XML as String"`?

Comment: Yes, NoMethodError: undefined method `symbolize_keys' for "Some XML as String":String

Comment: How are you handling your `"Some XML as String"` in your controller ? `params` should be a hash

Comment: I added it in a bit more detail how it currently works under 4.2.10.

Comment: The controller handles the xml with Nokogiri, get it via request.body.read

Answer (score 3):

I've been able to POST raw data using Rails 5.1.4 by setting it directly in the request for a controller spec

```
@request.env['RAW_POST_DATA'] = '<test>some raw xml</test>'
post :show
```

In the controller this can then be read via the request.body.read

```
> request.body.read
=> "<test>some raw xml</test>"
```

Note that this will not work when moving to Rails 5.2.  In that case the request body will be empty as the underlying behavior has changed.  The best way I've found to test this scenario is to use Request Specs instead of Controller Specs.

Controller specs - A controller spec is an RSpec wrapper for a Rails functional test. It allows you to simulate a single http request in each example, and then specify expected outcomes

Request specs - Request specs provide a thin wrapper around Rails' integration tests, and are designed to drive behavior through the full stack, including routing (provided by Rails) and without stubbing (that's up to you).

Here is an example posting that same data via a Request Spec:

```
post items_path, env: {'RAW_POST_DATA' => "<test>some raw xml</test>"}
```

In the controller

```
> request.body.read
=> "<test>some raw xml</test>"
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the above answers worked for me in Rails 5.2.2.

I was using code like this `@request.env['RAW_POST_DATA'] = json` in 5.1 in some cases where I needed a special type of serialization and I converted all of those to:

```
json = { "some" => "JSON" }.to_json
post :show, body: json
```

Comment: This is the only thing out of dozens of attempts that worked for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can pass raw body in the minitest:

```
post :show, as: :xml, headers: { 'RAW_POST_DATA': 'Some XML as String' }
```

[You can't use `params`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#what-to-include-in-your-functional-tests) because it's not suppose to be used in this way, also you need to add `as: :xml` becuase you send raw body with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type.

In the controller [`request.raw_body`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b2eb1d1c55a59fee1e6c4cba7030d8ceb524267c/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb#L311)

Comment: It says ArgumentError: unknown keyword: headers.

Comment: It's valid syntax for new Rails versions also I've tested it and it works as expect.